# Which way I can get ListBox item coords?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, coordinates

I want get Top, Left, Right and Bottom of item inside ListBox to show TextBox over it for item edit purpose.

For example: I need to know the Top-Left corner coords and Bottom-Right ones.

I read msdn and there are ListBox.IndexFromPoint method, but I need the opposite one, which is not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`ListBox.GetItemRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.getitemrectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you could use:

```
var rect = myListBox.GetItemRectangle(1);
```

Comment: Ugh why they didn't named this method in PointFromIndex style. Thank you.